# Haskell - Happy - "No instance ..." error

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

I'm trying to get familiar with Happy parser generator for Haskell. Currently, I have an example from the documentation but when I compile the program, I get an error.
This is the code:

```
{
module Main where
import Data.Char
}

%name calc
%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }

%token 
      let             { TokenLet }
      in              { TokenIn }
      int             { TokenInt $$ }
      var             { TokenVar $$ }
      '='             { TokenEq }
      '+'             { TokenPlus }
      '-'             { TokenMinus }
      '*'             { TokenTimes }
      '/'             { TokenDiv }
      '('             { TokenOB }
      ')'             { TokenCB }

%%

Exp   : let var '=' Exp in Exp  { \p -> $6 (($2,$4 p):p) }
      | Exp1                    { $1 }

Exp1  : Exp1 '+' Term           { \p -> $1 p + $3 p }
      | Exp1 '-' Term           { \p -> $1 p - $3 p }
      | Term                    { $1 }

Term  : Term '*' Factor         { \p -> $1 p * $3 p }
      | Term '/' Factor         { \p -> $1 p `div` $3 p }
      | Factor                  { $1 }

Factor                    
      : int                     { \p -> $1 }
      | var                     { \p -> case lookup $1 p of
                                    Nothing -> error "no var"
                                    Just i  -> i }
      | '(' Exp ')'             { $2 }

{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"

data Token
      = TokenLet
      | TokenIn
      | TokenInt Int
      | TokenVar String
      | TokenEq
      | TokenPlus
      | TokenMinus
      | TokenTimes
      | TokenDiv
      | TokenOB
      | TokenCB
 deriving Show

lexer :: String -> [Token]
lexer [] = []
lexer (c:cs) 
      | isSpace c = lexer cs
      | isAlpha c = lexVar (c:cs)
      | isDigit c = lexNum (c:cs)
lexer ('=':cs) = TokenEq : lexer cs
lexer ('+':cs) = TokenPlus : lexer cs
lexer ('-':cs) = TokenMinus : lexer cs
lexer ('*':cs) = TokenTimes : lexer cs
lexer ('/':cs) = TokenDiv : lexer cs
lexer ('(':cs) = TokenOB : lexer cs
lexer (')':cs) = TokenCB : lexer cs

lexNum cs = TokenInt (read num) : lexer rest
      where (num,rest) = span isDigit cs

lexVar cs =
   case span isAlpha cs of
      ("let",rest) -> TokenLet : lexer rest
      ("in",rest)  -> TokenIn : lexer rest
      (var,rest)   -> TokenVar var : lexer rest

main = getContents >>= print . calc . lexer
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( gr.hs, gr.o )

gr.hs:310:24:
No instance for (Show ([(String, Int)] -> Int))
  arising from a use of `print'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Show ([(String, Int)] -> Int))
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `print'
In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `print . calc . lexer'
In the expression: getContents >>= print . calc . lexer
```

Do you know why and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you examine the error message

```
No instance for (Show ([(String, Int)] -> Int))
  arising from a use of `print'
```

it's clear that the problem is that you are trying to `print` a function. And indeed, the value produced by the parser function `calc` is supposed to be a function which takes a lookup table of variable bindings and gives back a result. See for example the rule for variables:

```
{ \p -> case lookup $1 p of
    Nothing -> error "no var"
    Just i  -> i }
```

So in `main`, we need to pass in a list for the `p` argument, for example an empty list. (Or you could add some pre-defined global variables if you wanted). I've expanded the point-free code to a `do` block so it's easier to see what's going on:

```
main = do
  input <- getContents
  let fn = calc $ lexer input
  print $ fn [] -- or e.g. [("foo", 42)] if you wanted it pre-defined
```

Now it works:

```
$ happy Calc.y
$ runghc Calc.hs <<< "let x = 1337 in x * 2"
2674
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. One more question: how can I make this to repeat, for example if I run it, it will evaluate only one expression, if I try to write two expressions separated by '\n', it will give me "parse error". For example, I want to do something like this: "let a = 10 - 3 '\n' a + 8".

Comment: @JohnSmith: Try replacing `getContents` with `getLine` and add a recursive call to `main` after the `print`. However, that example won't work, as this program is designed to parse one expression at a time. There is no provision for defining variables that can be used in another expression, so that would require bigger changes to the program.